# Please tell me why this isn't working! (basic jquery)

Tags: jquery, html

**Script**

```
 function myfn(){
    var id= jQuery(this).find('input').val();
    alert(id);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
   <img src=".." onclick="myfn()" >
   <input type=hidden value=1 >
 </div>
```

The function is proper but the id value shows undefined. I have included all the necessary apis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the event source using this to myfn, also you need next instead of find, as find will look in descendants and next will look siblings.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bd4p8hLh/)

*Javascript*

```
 function myfn(obj){
    var id= jQuery(obj).next('input').val();
    alert(id);
  }
```

*In html*

```
 <div>
   <img src=".." onclick="myfn(this)" >
   <input type="hidden" value="1" >
 </div>
```

As a additional note

- Close `input` and `img` tags with `/`
- Enclose the attribute values in double quotes, e.g. `type` and `value`.

You can bind event using jQuery click instead of inline event bind you have in question. I would suggest you to use a class to bind event, for this you need to assign class to img. This will make the this and $(this) available in the handler.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bd4p8hLh/1/)

*Html*

```
<img src=".." onclick="myfn(this)" class="my-class">
```

*Javacript / jQuery*

```
$('.my-class').click(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).next('input').val();
    alert(id);
})
```

Comment: Man! You're a life saver! Thanks! Can you tell me why "this" wasn't working?!

Comment: Because you are binding event using javascript inline event binding.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" id="myimg" />
    <input type="hidden" value="1" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myimg').click(function myfn(){
    var id= jQuery(this).next('input').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

[`Live Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/t2bg9cr5/1/)

```js
$('#myimg').click(function myfn() {
  var id = jQuery(this).next('input').val();
  alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1" id="myimg" />
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are searching for a input element in the img.
You need to look for that input element in parent div or in next element.

Try this

```
function myfn(){
    var id= jQuery(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
    alert(id);
  }
```